# I am trying to use AJAX to change the orderby and order arguments in a WP_Query, but I can't determine why my code won't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

So I've been working on this for hours now. About 6 of them with no breaks and I cannot understand why this isn't working.

So I have this form:

```
<div id="wp-ajax-filter-search" class="full">
        <form action="" method="get">
            <div class="flex filters-grid">
                <div id="#sortBy" class="flex filters-dropdown">
                    <p class="filters-title">
                        Sort By
                    </p>
                    <div class="filters-options">
                        <input class="wp-drop-filter-item" type="radio" id="alphabetically" value="title" name="sort_filter">
                            <label for="alphabetically">
                                Alphabetically
                            </label>
                        <input class="wp-drop-filter-item" type="radio" id="datenew2old" value="ASC" name="sort_filter">
                            <label for="datenew2old">
                                Date Added (New to Old)
                            </label>
                        <input class="wp-drop-filter-item" type="radio" id="dateold2new" value="DESC" name="sort_filter">
                            <label for="dateold2new">
                                Date Added (Old to New)
                            </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="#countries" class="flex filters-dropdown">
                    <p class="filters-title">
                        Country
                    </p>
                    <?php
                    // set up a new query for each category, pulling in related posts.
                    $destinations = new WP_Query(
                        array(
                            'showposts'      => -1,
                            'post_type'      => 'destinations',
                            'post_status'    => 'publish',
                            'order_by' => 'title',
                            'order' => 'ASC'
                        )
                    );
                    if ($destinations->have_posts()):
                    ?>
                        <div class="filters-options">
                            <input class="wp-drop-filter-item <?php echo $country_slug ?>" type="radio" id="any" value="any" name="country_filter">
                                <label for="any">
                                    Any
                                </label>
                            <?php while ($destinations->have_posts()) : $destinations->the_post(); 
                            global $post;
                            $post_slug = $post->post_name;?>
                            <input class="wp-drop-filter-item country-option" type="radio" id="<?php echo $post_slug ?>" value="<?php echo $post->ID ?>" name="country_filter" >
                                <label for="<?php echo $post_slug; ?>">
                                    <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
                                </label>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                            <?php
                                // Reset things, for good measure
                                $destinations = null;
                                wp_reset_postdata();
                            ?>

                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
                <div id="#regions" class="flex filters-dropdown">
                    <p class="filters-title">
                        Region <span class="extra">(Choose Country First)</span>
                    </p>
                    <?php
                    // set up a new query for each category, pulling in related posts.
                    $regions = new WP_Query(
                        array(
                            'showposts'      => -1,
                            'post_type'      => 'regions',
                            'post_status'    => 'publish',
                            'order_by'       => 'title',
                            'order'          => 'ASC'
                        )
                    );
                    if ($regions->have_posts()):
                    ?>
                        <div class="filters-options">
                            <input class="wp-drop-filter-item" type="radio" id="any-region" value="any" name="region_filter">
                            <label class="region-option" for="any-region">
                                    Any
                            </label>
                            <?php while ($regions->have_posts()) : $regions->the_post(); 
                            global $post;
                            $post_slug = $post->post_name;
                            $country = get_field( "country", $post ); 
                            $country_slug = get_post_field( 'post_name', $country ); ?> 
                            <input class="wp-drop-filter-item" type="radio" id="<?php echo $post_slug ?>" value="<?php echo $post->ID ?>" name="region_filter">
                            <label class="region-option <?php echo $country_slug ?>" for="<?php echo $post_slug; ?>">
                                <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
                            </label>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                            <?php
                                // Reset things, for good measure
                                $regions = null;
                                wp_reset_postdata();
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <ul id="ajax_filter_search_results" class="destinations grid"></ul>
    </div>
```

Whenever you change one of the radio buttons, AJAX is triggered using this JS code:

```
var wpmafs = $("#wp-ajax-filter-search"); 
var wpmafsForm = wpmafs.find("form"); 


$(".wp-drop-filter-item").on("change",function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 

    var sort_filter = $("input[name='sort_filter']:checked").val();
    var country_filter = $("input[name='country_filter']:checked").val();
    var region_filter = $("input[name='region_filter']:checked").val();

    var data = {
        action : "wp_ajax_filter_search",
        sort_filter : sort_filter,
        country_filter : country_filter,
        region_filter : region_filter
    };
    
    console.log(data);
    
    $.ajax({
        url : ajax_url,
        data : data,
        success : function(response) {
            grid = $( "#ajax_filter_search_results" );
            wpmafs.find(grid).empty();
            if(response) {
                for(var i = 0 ;  i < response.length ; i++) {
                    var html = '<a class="grid-item destination" href="' + response[i].permalink + '">';
                        html += '<p class="grid-item-title">' + response[i].title + '</p>';
                        html += '<ul class="features">';
                        var features = response[i].features;
                        for(var k = 0 ;  k < features.length ; k++){
                            if(k > 3) break;
                            html += '<li> <img width="8" height="8" src="/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/golf-escapes-sussex-uk-packages-benefits-copy.svg" class="attachment-medium size-medium">' + features[k]['point'] + '</li>';
                        }
                        html += '</ul>';
                        html += '<div class="bg-img">';
                        html +=     '<img src="' + response[i].image_url + '">';
                        html += '</div>';
                        html += '</a>';
                        wpmafs.find(grid).append(html);
                }
            } else {
                var html  = "<li class='no-result'>No matches found. Try a different filter.</li>";
                wpmafs.find(grid).append(html);
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            grid = $( "#ajax_filter_search_results" );
            wpmafs.find(grid).empty();
            var html  = "<li class='no-result'>It appears we're having some technical difficulties. Please try again shortly or call us.</li>";
            wpmafs.find(grid).append(html);
        }
    });
});
```

And here's the AJAX function:

```
function wp_ajax_filter_search_callback() {
 
    header("Content-Type: application/json"); 
    
    if(isset($GET['sort_filter'])) {
        $sortval = $GET['sort_filter'];
        if($sortval == 'title'){
            $orderby = $sortval;
            $order = 'ASC';
        } elseif ($sortval == 'ASC' || $sortval == 'DESC'){
            $orderby = 'date';
            $order = $sortval;
        } else {
            $orderby = 'title';
            $order = 'ASC';
        }
    };
    
    if(isset($_GET['country_filter'])) {
        $location = $_GET['country_filter'];
        if ($location != 'any'){
            $loc_query[] = array(
                'key' => 'country',
                'value' => $location,
                'compare' => "IN",
            );
        }
    };
    
    if(isset($_GET['region_filter'])) {
        $region = $_GET['region_filter'];
        if ($region != 'any'){
            $region_query[] = array(
                'key' => 'region',
                'value' => $region,
                'compare' => "IN",
            );
        }
    };  
    
    $meta_query = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        $loc_query,
        $region_query,
    );
    
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'hotels',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => $orderby,
        'order' => $order,
        'meta_query' => $meta_query
    );
    
 
    $search_query = new WP_Query( $args );
 
    if ( $search_query->have_posts() ) {
 
        $result = array();
 
        while ( $search_query->have_posts() ) {
            $search_query->the_post();
 
            $result[] = array(
                "id" => get_the_ID(),
                "title" => get_the_title(),
                "permalink" => get_permalink(),
                "image_url" => get_the_post_thumbnail_url('', 'medium-large'),
                "features" => get_field('featured_offer')
            );
        }
        wp_reset_query();
 
        echo json_encode($result);
 
    } else {
        
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

I have used this code before on another website, so I know that it *can* work, but it's not working in this instance.

The country_filter and region_filter radio buttons are working. When you change them the AJAX call runs, and the wp_query is actually filtered.

The problem, however, is that the sort_filter radio button won't work for some reason.

So, to test I've been putting `print_r("some random bit of text")` and checking the network tab in my browsers inspector to see if that text appears in the Request. Under `if(isset($_GET['country_filter']))` and `if(isset($_GET['region_filter']))`, the text displays. But, if I put it under `if(isset($_GET['sort_filter']))` it doesn't display.

So, clearly, the AJAX code is getting to the `if(isset($_GET['sort_filter']))` line and saying "Nope, it's not set". But it is.

And if I use console.log() in the JS code to log the data that is being sent to the AJAX call, I can clearly see that the value of the selected sort_filter radio button is being sent:

```
{action: 'wp_ajax_filter_search', sort_filter: 'title', country_filter: undefined, region_filter: undefined}
```

The request URL in the Network tab also has that information in it, for example:

```
https://my.staging.url/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wp_ajax_filter_search&sort_filter=title
```

Despite all that, I can't get the AJAX code to $GET the sort_filter radio button value and use it in the WP_Query.

Any help is totally appreciated. I'm going to get some shut-eye for a bit as I've completely burnt myself out on this but I look forward to seeing what help anyone can offer because this really is driving me up the wall and the deadline is fast approaching.

Enormous thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider also asking this on the [WordPress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You appear to have 2 typos. In if(isset($GET['sort_filter'])) {
        $sortval = $GET['sort_filter']; ie you are missing the _ in $_GET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your ajax callback function you have

```
if(isset($GET['sort_filter'])) {
    $sortval = $GET['sort_filter'];
```

and it should be

```
if(isset($_GET['sort_filter'])) {
    $sortval = $_GET['sort_filter'];
```

ie you are missing the _ out of both calls to $_GET

Comment: I hate that it was this simple but sometimes you stare at something for so long that you just go blind. 

Thanks for your answer, guess I just needed another pair of eyes on it!

Comment: Pro tip. Use a good IDE like VSCode or PhpStorm. It will highlight undeclared stuff.